# Blackberry - DatabaseIOException when creating database in store folder

Tags: database, sqlite, blackberry, java-me, io

In my app i am creating database,its working well in 9000 simulator but it throws  "DatabaseIOException can not  create folder file:///store/Databases/" exception  when testing on 9700 simulator and in 8900 device.What is the problem please help me.

Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You generally can't create folders or add files from the root of the /store filesystem.   Try "/store/home/user"

Comment: I used above path but it shows "file system not ready" exception in 9700 simulator

Comment: @koti For "filesystem not ready" see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4447526/blackberry-sqlite-db-creation-filesystem-not-ready/4451954#4451954

Comment: Thank You.I understood the problem